# how would I create a program that would sort text files like this in js

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have a text file structured like this:

Newborn  adj. Recently born.

Newly  adv. 1 recently. 2 afresh, anew.

New wave  n. A style of rock music.

how would I separate the word and the definition in two different text files for the whole array so that I would have a words.txt file in javascript

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate each line of the text with the separators `["n.","adv.","adj." ...etc.]` Look at your file to identify all of them, read the file line by line and use `split()` by one of these separators.

**Demo:**

```js
const myText = `Newborn adj. Recently born.
Newly adv. 1 recently. 2 afresh, anew.
New wave n. A style of rock music.
`;

const getSeparator = (separators, target) => {
  for (const separator of separators) {
    if (target.includes(separator)) return separator;
  }
};

const separators = [`adj.`, `adv.`, `n.`];

for (const line of myText.split(`\n`)) {
  console.log(line);
  const separator = getSeparator(separators, line);
  const splitLines = line.split(separator).map((s) => s.trim());
  console.log(splitLines);
}
```